# What does this notation mean: $\cfrac{\partial (\Psi,\xi)}{\partial (x,y)}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation, partial-derivative

What does this notation mean: $\cfrac{\partial (\Psi,\xi)}{\partial (x,y)}$ ?

It's from an old paper published in 1953. It could be an old notation that is not used anymore, but I am not sure what it means.

**Context:**

> [image: paper screenshot]

**Reference:** Kawaguti, M. (1953). Numerical solution of the Navier-Stokes equations for the flow around a circular cylinder at Reynolds number 40. Journal of the Physical Society of Japan, 8(6), 747-757.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern usage it typically denotes the Jacobian matrix of the mapping $(x,y)\mapsto (\Psi,\zeta).$ In this case, it is being used to denote the determinant of this matrix, i.e. $$\cfrac{\partial (\Psi,\xi)}{\partial (x,y)}=\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial y}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}.$$ See [this Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Stream_function_for_2D_equations), where you can find a very similar equation for time-dependent flow.

Comment: Thank you. I should have checked NS's wikipedia page first :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a notation for the determinant  of partial derivatives. $$\cfrac{\partial(\Psi,\xi)}{\partial (x,y)}= $$

$$ det \begin {bmatrix} \frac{\partial  \Psi}{ \partial x} &\frac{\partial  \Psi}{ \partial y} \\    \frac{\partial  \xi}{\partial x} &\frac{\partial  \xi}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}  $$